# Three users voted to deleted an answer that I was working to improve while I was discussing improvements with another user. Please help!

Tags: discussion

[Post in Question](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/64867/timeline)
I posted an answer that was factual and provided evidence that misinformation was being perpetuated by tweets that Elon Musk made, which led the person asking the question to make an incorrect assumption about the feasibility of rail-gun assisted launch.

Three members of the community voted to delete the answer. These people did not comment or provide reasons. I don't know how to contact them. However, the site's guidelines say...

> When should I vote to delete an answer?
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
> The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

I don't think that any of these reasons apply here. I would like to ask if people could review the answer, upvote it, and vote to undelete it. I know that there are lots of fans of Elon Musk out there and I am, on the whole, one of them. But I place a higher priority on stamping out the spread of misinformation than being a fan of Elon Musk's accomplishments.

[Link to video link in the image below](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uMmVYYMcXU&list=TLPQMDIwODIwMjPoePqlQh_sAg&t=371s&ab_channel=FraserCain) (Note: this is not me or someone that I know speaking in the video)
[image: Answer that was deleted 1]
[image: Answer that was deleted 2]

Answer (score 6):

From a review of the answers you have posted so far, I think there are good grounds for deletion for most of them on Low Quality and Not Attempting to Answer the Question.

You also link to videos which either don't support your assertions, or are very dubious in their provenance, and that all seem to be from the same YouTube channel, which smells a lot like spam.

You see there are a number of strikes against you, Phil.

I would advise reading our [tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and [How to Answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) pages thoroughly so you can understand what we expect in an answer post.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking a look Rory. I reviewed the links you provided and I am willing to try to improve. I only linked two videos each on different channels: a Fraser Cain interview, and a presentation that I gave at Ascend where I described a novel launch system. But, on Tuesday I got carried away and answered three questions related to my field of research. I suppose that some people thought I was spamming the site and reacted negatively. Unfortunate. I do, however, respectfully disagree that these answers are low quality and/or do not attempt to answer the questions.

Comment: I'd like to take another crack at answering a question in a way that doesn't trigger the community's spam concerns. But, to do that I think I need to be able to delete the old answer first as it looks like a contributor can only try to answer a question once. Would you be willing to undelete https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41135/what-are-the-biggest-challenges-for-high-altitude-rail-gun-launch-systems so that I can delete the answer instead?