# Reputation graph shows upwards plot, but the value is stuck at 1 - Bug?

Tags: discussion, bug

This is about this user: https://space.stackexchange.com/users/22203/phil1008. If you go to Activity dashboard, you will see the reputation graph has an upward plot, but the rep value is stuck at 1.

[image]

The user has two answers which accumulates to 10 upvotes and 1 downvote. So, the rep value should be 99 (which is the same value in the graph). There is [another discussion](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/three-users-voted-to-deleted-an-answer-that-i-was-working-to-improve-while-i-was) related to deleted answer, but that doesn't explain the rep plunging to 1. The user doesn't seem to be suspended. Any explanation on this?

Comment: That seems to be a bug - I cannot see anything from a mod perspective that would do this, so we'll need to await staff response.

Comment: Negative posts removed by the Roomba do not have the author's reputation points restored.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the reputation points is now "restored".

[image]

But it doesn't explain why the reputation was stuck at "1" temporarily. Maybe some staff will check and comment.